# MS test + EF (VS2008): when running all tests: errors about different ObjectContexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2008, mstest

In Visual Studio 2008, C#, Entity Framework 3.5, MS Test, I have two tests:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test1()
{
    using (Entities context = new Entities())
    {
        using (TransactionHelper transaction = new TransactionHelper(context))
        {
            // Stuff

            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test2()
{
    using (Entities context = new Entities())
    {
        using (TransactionHelper transaction = new TransactionHelper(context))
        {
            // Stuff

            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

When running them individually, they both pass. But when I run all tests, it says the following for the second test:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The relationship between the two
>   objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different
>   ObjectContext objects..

I do not understand this at all. Nowhere in the codepath do I create a new Entities object. I checked several times (and seeing as how the code works in indivual test runs *and* production use, that must be true). And I even wrapped the Entities in a using statement.

Is there some weird retention in the TestContext perhaps?

For reference, the TransactionHelper (simplified):

```
public class TransactionHelper : IDisposable
{
    private global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext _context;
    private ConnectionState _initialConState;
    private DbTransaction _transaction;

    public TransactionHelper(global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext context)
    {   
        _context = context;
        _initialConState = context.Connection.State;

        if (_initialConState != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            _context.Connection.Open(); // open connection if not already open
        }

        _transaction = _context.Connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        _transaction.Rollback();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _transaction.Commit();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _transaction.Dispose();

        if (_initialConState != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            _context.Connection.Close(); // only close connection if not initially open
        }
    }
}
```

It makes no difference if I use isolation level `ReadCommitted`.

Comment: Have you checked for any static objects referenced by both tests?

Comment: Good thinking. I just searched for all instanced of 'static' in the entire project, but none could be the problem. I'll expand the search beyond the project.

Comment: It did turn out to be that one static dictionary, which stored objects in a cache. I really don't get it, they're not even entity objects. They're just very simple objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since unit tests should ideally be totally independent of each other (in terms of state, order, etc), Visual Studio and other test frameworks such as NUnit speed up the execution process by running them in parallel. Shared static resources usually turned out to be the culprit for me in cases like yours.

It might be that these simple objects you mention (e.g some lookup values) get assigned to a property of an entity object, and then in the second test you assign the same simple object to an entity of another context, which would raise an error like you mentioned.

If this is the case then you might try mocking the cache in your tests (or maybe minimize the use of `static`).

Comment: I added a ClearCache() method which I call at the beginning of each test. It slows it down, but it fixes it :)